# Getting 415 Error on updating using PUT method

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt, put, http-status-code-415

I am using JWT spring security in backend and I would like to update user details in angular using PUT method. But I am getting 415 error on update.

Update method in springboot
controller

```
@PutMapping("/UpdateUser/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUsers(@PathVariable("id") Long id,@RequestBody User user){
    User update = userService.updateUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(update, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Angular service

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { UserAuthService } from './user-auth.service';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class UserService {
      PATH_OF_API = 'http://localhost:9090';
    
      requestHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'No-Auth': 'True' });
      constructor(
        private httpclient: HttpClient,
        private userAuthService: UserAuthService
      ) {}
    
      public sign(signData){
        return this.httpclient.post(this.PATH_OF_API + '/registerNewUser',signData,{
          headers:this.requestHeader
        });
      }
    
    
      updateUser(userId:number,user){
        return this.httpclient.put(this.PATH_OF_API + '/UpdateUser/'+userId,userId,user);
      }
}

Error
```

[image: Error image]

```
Request URL: http://localhost:9090/UpdateUser/1663565697945
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 415 
Remote Address: [::1]:9090
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response header**
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2022 16:35:21 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
**Request header**
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJrZWVydGhpMTIzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjYzNjE4MTc0LCJpYXQiOjE2NjM2MDAxNzR9.2YxIgdM78TZDNpwFIkB_-KfZ4DwlWKlN7Xzf4V4D2g4kCQr7kJdpx0ExbN9CTWAxtokzjlk_K22ROQEzBgGKnw
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/plain
Host: localhost:9090
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
```

{
"timestamp":"2022-09-19T16:35:21.514+00:00",
"status":415,
"error":"Unsupported Media Type",
"message":"",
"path":"/UpdateUser/1663565697945"
}

How can I solve this error. Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is the request body, ie. the `user` going as JSON? Unsupported Mediatype is generally due to mismatch of the content type in request and the server

Comment: Yes, it is going as json

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1.Your request in the Angular service has too many parameters, put request
in general should include body only, in your case the user object.

Try change this:

```
return this.httpclient.put(this.PATH_OF_API + '/UpdateUser/'+userId,userId,user);
```

To somthing like this:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

 return this.http.put(`${PATH_OF_API}/UpdateUser/${userId}`, JSON.stringify(user), httpOptions);
```

2. You updating the user and you include the id in the path, the id should be send
   as part of the body, it should be included in your Angular object.

So ideally, your contrller will have only RequestBody and the Angular service will
look like:

```
 return this.http.put(`${PATH_OF_API}/UpdateUser`, JSON.stringify(user), httpOptions);
```